# How do I see how much CPU time my firewall uses?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, performance, firewall

I was attacked with a [DNS Amplification](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/237127/why-would-hackers-attack-a-dns-with-a-dos) and as a result added nearly 4,000 IP addresses to my firewall using `fail2ban`.

I have seen many people worried about how many rules they include in their firewall. From what I remember looking at the kernel code, the loops are very tight so I don't think that a mere 4,000 IPs is going to make things slow.

So my question is: How do I determine how much CPU time my firewall is currently taking?

Bonus Question: Are there ways to optimize your rules so they go as fast as possible?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but maybe a solution to your problem?  https://serverfault.com/questions/919955/iptables-consumes-a-lot-of-cpu-when-blocking-many-ips/919959   And the downvote wasn't mine.

Comment: @tink That's a very good answer to the Bonus Question! Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure =} ... let us know how you got on ;)

Comment: Sorry 'bout my answer last night. I *normally* stop browsing after I take my dose of Ambien.